# java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture not working on multiple screens configuration with last JRE (8)

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have two screens plugged on my computer.
I try to make a screen capture on each screen.
I'm using the following code :

```
GraphicsDevice[] screens = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();  //same screens[] with JRE7 and JRE8

Robot rbt0 = new Robot(screens[0]);
BufferedImage image0 = rbt0.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,1024,1024));

Robot rbt1 = new Robot(screens[1]);
BufferedImage image1 = rbt1.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,1024,1024));
```

- On JRE7, each capture is performed on the right screen : image0 and image1 are different.
- On JRE8, the capture is the same for both screens : image0 and image1 is the same visual image (they are both images of the screen 0).

The javadoc doesn't mention there is a new feature about Robot class on JRE8.
Is this a bug of the JRE8 ? Is anyone having the same problem ? 
If this bug is confirmed, how could I communicate this problem to Oracle ?

Thanks everyone,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the way screen coordinates are calculated by the Robot have changed.

The following bug has been raised against the javadoc of Java 8 which may explain your problem.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8033128

It looks like the change was made deliberately and is not a bug.

To capture your second screen you may have to offset the location by the size of the first screen.

```
Robot rbt1 = new Robot(screens[1]);
BufferedImage image1 = rbt1.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(1024,0,1024,1024));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are absolutely right. the screen number is no more relevant to capture on the right screen. Now we have to deal with coordinates. The problem is, if the second screen is on the left on the main screen, the x coordinate is negative. If the second screen is on the right of the main screen, the x coordinate is positive. How do i know if the screen i want to work on is on the left or on the right of the main screen ?

Comment: @burgerLove You should able to get the coordinates for each screen from the configuration of each GraphicsDevice object.  Take a look at the beginning of the GrahpicsDevice javadoc for an example. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html

Comment: how do you know the changes were made deliberately? so is this still a but then or not? will it be fixed?

Comment: @ZetCoby I don't. It's an assumption based on Oracle updating the javadoc to match the new behavior.  The documentation bug I linked has not been corrected so they may still revert back to the old behavior.